# How does a value in the array move with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm sorting a list of online members in the chat list. I want to keep my value at the top. How can I make the shortest possible way?

```
// MY Jquery Code JS
var list = [
  {"userid":"19380","username":"User54660"},
  {"userid":"10908","username":"User63466"},
  {"userid":"10908","username":"My Name"},
  {"userid":"10908","username":"User34840"}
];

var htmlOut = "";
$.each(list, function(index, value) {
  htmlOut += '<li class="my">' + value.username + '</li>'               
});
$('#__ajaxOnlineList').append(htmlOut);
```

```html
<!-- Normal Output HTML  -->
<ul id="__ajaxOnlineList">  
  <li>User54660</li>
  <li>User63466</li>
  <li class="my-rank">My Name</li>
  <li>User34840</li>
 </ul>

 <!-- Desired Result HTML -->
 <ul id="__ajaxOnlineList">
   <li class="my-rank">My Name</li>
   <li>User54660</li>
   <li>User63466</li>
   <li>User34840</li>
 </ul>
```

Current output

[image]

Desired output

[image]

**LAST CODE:**
 [image: last code]

Comment: Normal Output HTML:
https://i.ibb.co/DLH7TMq/Screenshot-2.png

Desired Result HTML:
https://i.ibb.co/KzLLC3Z/Screenshot-1.png

Comment: The above code can't output the "normal" html output, since `my-rank` is never set. What is the criteria to determine which user should have `my-rank`?

Comment: `$('.my-rank').prependTo('#__ajaxOnlineList')` Will work, however the JS code you've shown does not set the `my-rank` class as shown in the HTML.

Comment: var myrank = 19380;

Comment: Is that part of the source above?

Comment: Besides, shouldn't that be first already?... Also, that element cannot lead `My name` to be on top of the list in any way.

Comment: yes I forgot to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the comment above, you just need to sort the original array returning to the highest position the element with the same rank as your variable.

```
// MY Jquery Code JS
var myrank = 19380; // retrieved from the comments above.
var list = [
  {"userid":"19380","username":"User54660"},
  {"userid":"10908","username":"User63466"},
  {"userid":"10908","username":"My Name"},
  {"userid":"10908","username":"User34840"}
].sort(item => +item.userid === myrank ? -1 : 1);


var htmlOut = "";
$.each(list, function(index, value) {
  var _hasClass = +value.userid === myrank;
  htmlOut += '<li' + _hasClass ? ' class="my-rank"' : ''+ '>' + value.username + '</li>'               
});
$('#__ajaxOnlineList').append(htmlOut);
```

The above code will take care of:

- Sorting the original list by pushing to the top of the array the item (s) with the same rank as the user id.
- Printing `class="my-rank"` on the item with the same criteria defined above.

The `+` used before `item.userid` or `value.userid` is used to cast the value to a number, so that the `===` assertion will work as expected.

As a side note, the sort is unnecessary in that case. I'm wondering how you are expecting it to work, since the rank provided is not the one of `My Name`.

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting by username, like:

```
const myrank = 19380;
list.sort(a => a.userid == myrank ? -1 : 1);

$.each(list, function(index, value) {
  const classname = value.userid == myrank ? 'myrank : '';
  htmlOut += `<li class="${classname}">${value.username}</li>`;               
});
```

This will keep the record having `userid == 19380` to the top and the others will follow. 
Of course, this will not sort the remaining as you might expect but you can do some further sorting.

Comment: You should cast the user id to a number, otherwise it won't sort, since strict equals will compare a string to a number, which will fail.

Comment: or just go for `==`

Comment: Which may lead to undesired behaviours like this one: https://jsfiddle.net/zwo4h5vg/ . http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Answer (score 0):

You can have a separate variable for your own name. Then append it first.

This might not be the *most elegant solution* but it will save a couple of loops instead of using `sort`

```js
var list = [
    {"userid":"19380","username":"User54660"},
    {"userid":"10908","username":"User63466"},
    {"userid":"10908","username":"My Name"},
    {"userid":"10908","username":"User34840"}
];

var username = "My Name";

var htmlOut = "", myHTML = "";
$.each(list, function(index, value) {
  if (value.username == username ) myHTML = '<li class="my-rank">' + value.username + '</li>';
  else htmlOut += '<li>' + value.username + '</li>';
});

$('#__ajaxOnlineList').append(myHTML + htmlOut);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="__ajaxOnlineList"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function _chatOnline() {
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: ajaxUrl + "ajax.chat.onlinelist.php?room=" + 
   chat_room,
   dataType: "json",
   data: { room : chat_room, userid : myID },
   cache: !1,
   success: function(a) {
       var htmlOut = "";
       var list = a.message.sort(item => item.userid === myID ? -1 : 1);           
        $.each(list, function(index, value) {
          var _hasClass = value.userid === myID;
          htmlOut += '<li' + (_hasClass ? ' class="you-desk"' : '') + '><span class="online-icon"></span><a href="javascript:void(0);">' + value.username + '</a></li>'               
        });

        //$("#_ajaxOnlineCount").text(a.message.online);
        $("#__ajaxOnlineList").html(htmlOut);
        setTimeout("_chatOnline()", 2555);
   }
 })
 }
```

Comment: Hi Alex, is this an answer to your question, if yes, please add how and why it solved your problem.